# can't display result on angular-ui typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

So i was trying to implement something like the [google map example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#typeahead) in the angular-ui bootstrap demo page, but i can't get the result display in the dropdown menu.

full code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/eIM7UC4HrIUXxdET3CO0?p=preview

this is what i have so far

**HTML**

```
<input required ng-model="asyncSelected" typeahead="address for address in getUserData($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue" type="text" placeholder="e.g john, david">
```

**angular controller**

```
  $scope.getUserData = function(val) {
            return $http.get('/sessionHandler/userProfileNameAndPicture/'+val, {
            }).then(function(userData){
              var addresses = [];
              console.log(userData) // see picture below 
              angular.forEach(userData.data, function(item){
                addresses.push(item);
              });
              return addresses;
            });
          };
```

**console.log(userData)**
[image]

i got the result back but i can't display it on the dropdown menu.

**UPDATE**:
after apply the answer from @Engineer 
[image]

i got this error: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pic you can see, that there is no `"results"` property(you use it in `.forEach` ) of the `data` array. Try to change your code to below one:

```
angular.forEach(userData.data, function(item){
                         //  ^--------   '.results' is removed
```

Comment: Hi @Engineer, thanks for your answer.I have apply the solution you suggested however i got this error instead "TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"